# Colour Overlay is tinting white background, how do I make it apply just to black pixels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have 2 layers in a photoshop document, both with black tonal imagery. I wish to apply 2 different colours to these black images, using the colour overlay effect. I am using 'screen' blend mode so that the colour only applies to the black image. Which seems to work when only one layer is visible. When both are turned on, the colour overlay on the top layer is tinting the white background of that layer, and therefore changing the colour of the image underneath, as I'm using the 'multiply' layer blend mode. If I cut a 'hole' in the white background I can see the true colour of the image underneath. How do I make the colour overlay just apply to the black pixels, and not to the white background? Thanks.

Comment: Do you perhaps need to erase the white background on your higher layer so that it contains only image and transparent pixels? It sounds like it should not have white in it. Also, some screen shots would really help us see what you're seeing.

Comment: It would be great if you share the images you want to apply colors too, or some similar images so that we can try that out too, and help you better.